# Moderately geeky cryptics

Tags: cryptic-clues

A few assorted cryptic clues. Mostly pretty straightforward, although some "geek" skills may be required to understand some elements.

Parts of one or two clues may be UK-centric. Apologies for those if they mean nothing.

> Galaxians plus other games included in retro-release of Frogger (4)
>
> Learner in education made around 2,130,706,433 (9)
>
> Willy entertainment sought by confused man in legal transgression (5,5)
>
> Wine served in 1815 and 1905 vintages (4)
>
> Blink 172's reworking of Tin Lizzie's "Decor" (2,5)
>
> You are an American, an enormous gassy mass spotted in Bath (6)
>
> Prototype GUI is confused with grownup Wow! for dorks (7,3,10)
>
> Kasparov's main rival in the 1990s (4,4)
>
> SELECT count(down), m, c FROM seven_db WHERE <condition> (5)
>
> This female friend was very
> popular for a while with Denise, Paula, and Fat Agnus (5)

Have fun.
Jer

**Extra info**

Hint 1

> Geeks don't necessarily express numbers in decimal

Answer (score 4):

**Partial answer**

Galaxians plus other games included in retro-release of Frogger (4)

> [Gorf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorf) - backwards within Frogger

Learner in education made around 2,130,706,433 (9)

> Localhost - 2,130,706,433 is the integer representation of "127.0.0.1". Don't fully understand the link to "learner in education".

Wine served in 1815 and 1905 vintages (4)

> Rosé - if we convert numbers to alphabet positions 18/15/19/05 becomes ROSE

Blink 172's reworking of Tin Lizzie's "Decor" (2,5)

> In Black - Tin Lizzie's were only sold in black. 172 in hexadecimal is 'ac' and "in black" is an anagram of "blink ac".

You are an American, an enormous gassy mass spotted in Bath (6)

> Uranus = Ur+an+US

Kasparov's main rival in the 1990s (4,4)

> [Deep Blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Blue_(chess_computer)) - as pointed out by Chris Cudmore, the colour #001990 is a deep blue.

This female friend was very popular for a while with Denise, Paula, and Fat Agnus (5)

> [Amiga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_Chip_Set)

Comment: How is the second last clue a cryptic clue? It seems like a straightforward definition.

Comment: All good so far. Hint 1 may help address the 2 queried answers?

Comment: Try googling #001990